# Regex - get class property value

Tags: php, regex

I have string like:

```
public $host = 'sth'; public $user = 'sth'; public $password = 'sth';public $db = 'dbname';        public $dbprefix = 'sth';
```

I want to get $db value dynamically. I tried regex:

```
#(.*)public(.*)$db(.*)=(.*)\'(.*)\';#is
```

empty array result

Please don't write I can get instance of class and property, because I can't and that's all. There is any more posibble than regex.

**Problem solved!**

```
$file="public $host = 'sth';        public $user = 'sth';        public $password = 'sth';        public $db = 'get this value';
        public $dbprefix = 'sth';";
$regex = "/.*public\s+$db\s+=\s+'(.*?)';/i";
preg_match($regex,$file,$matches);
echo '<br><pre>';var_dump($matches);
```

$matches[1] is 'get this value';

Comment: Why are you capturing all your `.*`s?

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm sure there is a better way to achieve what you want, here is a regex that should match the value of `$db`:

```
/public\s+\$db\s*=\s*'(.*?)';/i
```

See it in use [here](http://regex101.com/r/bN5cG1/2).

Comment: To be specific, the problem was the unescaped `$`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Not just that, `\'(.*)\'` matched more than OP wanted, I made it non-greedy.

Comment: `preg_match('/public\s+\$db\s+=\s+\'(.*?)\';/i',$file,$matches);` empty array

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this,

```
<?php
$mystring = <<<'EOD'
public $host = 'sth'; public $user = 'sth'; public $password = 'sth';public $db = 'dbname';        public $dbprefix = 'sth';";
EOD;
$regex = '~(?<=public \$db = \')[^\']*~';
preg_match_all($regex, $mystring, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "dbname"
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to escape the `$` symbol in the input like i did on my example.

Comment: I can't. String is dynamic and I can't change anything there

Comment: @turson now you don't need to escape $ in the input.